# VS 2015 uses old TypeScript version

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015. I've just installed TypeScript 1.6.3, restarted VS 2015 and VS seems to be still using an old tsc version: (btw the setup said [Repair], so I suppose this version was already installed)

I've checked what tsc version I am using via PM console:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.2.0.10516

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> tsc -v
Version 1.0.3.0
PM>
```

I've also checked my .csproj file and found:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

and

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Are you basing this conclusion on what the package manager says you have installed? I don't know where it's getting that version from but it's probably a different place than where vs is looking. BTW - if you delete the typescript version property from your project file it will always target the latest.

Comment: I followed the instructions about how to know which typescript version VS is using. Although I have doubt. I found 4 versions of TypeScript compliler in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript" folder. When I deleted the 1.0 subfolder PM started to report 1.4.0.0. When I deleted 1.4 subfolder PM started to not found tsc... weird

Answer (score 2):

inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript delete all the folders exept 1.7

then run in terminal

```
tsc -v
```

if nothing run

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and after

```
tsc -v
```

and you should see 1.7 version

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for this is the fatal combination of...

1. Having multiple versions of TypeScript installed
2. Having more thn one of the versions in your PATH variable

If you go and remove all but the most recent version of TypeScript from the PATH environment variable, that will stop `tsc` commands picking up the wrong one.